# White/Blank Screen in local host upon saving import from "./components" in App.jsx (following React/THREE.JS Tutorial)

Tags: reactjs, three.js, tailwind-css, vite

I've been following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fYi8SGA20k&t=71s) from Javascript Mastery on building a 3D portfolio, but when I save at the point in the video at 19:43 (implementing the import statement in the title above) I only get a blank screen. There are no red-line errors in VSCode and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. I'd be very grateful for any help with the issue. 
My code is pictured below

[App.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCRyg.png)

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHDgR.png)

[components folder set-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VD0kx.png)

[index.js inside of components folder (not inside canvas)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQsG3.png)

The tutorial shows that the Vite Server should show a black screen with Hero and Navbar pictured as text in the upper left corner of the website